# Smart power outlet

Tags: outlet

Is there such a thing as a power outlet that detects when a device is wanting to draw power (to operate) and turns on, and turns off when the device is not operating?

Icing on the cake would be that the outlet would have programmable tresholds! I googled around for a bit but I could only find timer-based outlets.

(This is related to a laptop charger)

Comment: Closest thing I've seen is a power strip with one master. If that starts to consume power over a predefined threshold, the other outlets are tured on.

Comment: If it turns off, how will the target device be able to draw power?

Comment: @Passerby I don't know, I'm not an electrical engineer! However, mag-safe from Apple does something simmilar where it outputs nearly nothing, and then after one second the charger emits the full output. However, there is smarter stuff going on with a data pin on the connector.

Comment: That's because they use a 1 wire protocol to verify that it is an apple charger and what wattage the charger is, as well as control the led. That is not an option on your retail laptop power supply, on the AC side.

Comment: @Passerby So I guess there is no way the outlet could know that whatever is plugged in needs more than the low output (representing off) that is given? What of the wattage that a wattage meter shows? Could nothing be done with that?

Comment: I can't think of a device off hand but I'm sure it's something that is capable of being made as a hobbyist project. I was thinking of some type of current sensing switch. I'm sure the switch works on some type of magnetic field for it toggle itself if a current is too high.

Comment: But I agree with @Passerby. If the device turns off, how would it be able to detect a higher current, let alone, be able to draw power and charge your device.

Comment: @KingDuken Well, I thought, maybe once the charger was plugged into the laptop, it would start outputting power, and thus also consuming more in the outlet? And then the outlet could see that and go like "Alright, I'll give you more". Clearly, I have no idea how electricity works! :)

Comment: if timing is not critical, you could have it turn completely off, then periodically startup for 5 seconds and check the amps drawn, and if under a threshold, go back to off for 30 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, kind of.

They're normally not totally off but in a very low power state.

This can be typical of portable USB-chargers. The main power circuit is off, but they're still detecting basically impedance on the output port. With everything disconnected it goes toward infinity. When you connect something the impedance drops to the input impedance of what you connected and then the main power stage is signalled to start.

Comment: Would it work to conserve the lifespan of my laptop charger? I leave it plugged in 24/7. Today I put my ear on it and I heard rattling and this charger is relatively new.

Comment: The rattling is probably coil noise. That's nothing to be worried normally. The coil which is a piece of wire wrapped around a ferrite can be have some of the mechanical resonance excited and you can hear the mechanical binration. Ussually referred to as coil whine. Your charger ( if it's a new notebook) is probably already in a very low power standby mode and manufacturers spend a lot of money on this because most people leave it plugged. So this standbycurrent can account to more energy than the one needed to charge the laptop. I wouldn't worry tbh.

Comment: Laptop chargers are designed to last quite a lot. They ussually fail if overheated (like putting them below a pillow) or in charging situations not in standby mode.

Comment: Alright thanks, it has a history of getting incredibly warm though. Like, nearly hurts to touch. But as long as it works I guess I'm fine. I thought it was due to leaving it plugged in all the time, but it could be because I lock it in a tight place sometimes (and cause heat issues).

Comment: Yes, it seems a little bit inoffensive, but if it's a commercial product I think it shouldn't exceed 50/60°C on the outside (don't know the regulations fully). If it's getting too hot you probably have it constrained. Don't put it ontop of pillows or enclose it since they rely on convection for cooling.